# Maven not downloading jars for dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, repository

I am trying to set up Maven on my Windows machine. I tried both 3.2.3 and 3.1.1. I installed the m2eclipse plugin in my eclipse.

I places the following dependencies in my pom.xml  (just as a sample)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Eclipse gives the error: `Missing artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:jar:1.1.7.RELEASE`

In my .m2 repository I have the .pom file, the .jar.lastUpdated file but no actual .jar file

When I execute `mvn -X clean install` I have the following stack trace

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SpringTest_Boot: Could not resolve dependencies for project SpringTest_Boot:SpringTest_Boot:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:sprin
g-boot-tools:jar:1.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates
 are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project SpringTest_Boot: Could not resolve dependencies for project SpringTest_Boot:SpringTest_Boot:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:jar:1.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the u
pdate interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:220)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoExecutor.java:257)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:200)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project SpringTest_Boot:SpringTest_Boot:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework.bo
ot:spring-boot-tools:jar:1.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or
 updates are forced
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:198)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:195)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:jar:1.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached i
n the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:192)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:jar:1.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in
the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:367)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-tools:jar:1.1.7.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the
local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:232)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:599)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:518)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
        ... 26 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
O:\Clouds\Dropbox\Repositories\git\Spring Comparison Test\Boot>mvn -X clean install
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you have used a version which exsts but couldn't be downloaded for whatever reason (Download problems / proxies etc.).

Within your local repository `${HOME}/.m2/repository/org.springframewokr/boot` you need to delete the folder `spring-boot-tools` and try to rebuild.

Apart from that the used artifacts is not a `jar` file it is a parent of a multi module build instead which can't be used as a dependency. You need to check the documentation which kind of artifacts you have to use.

**Update:**

Based on the docs you have to define your pom differently:

```xml
<project...>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: this happens even after I try that

Comment: I cleared out the pom file, readded my dependencies, and it now no longer complains..

Answer (score 0):

If I look at the maven website: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot

I can't find the 1.1.7.RELEASE version. Only the 1.1.6.RELEASE version. Try:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I found the version using search.maven.org.   The same happened even with your suggested version

Comment: I tried even the basic spring-web dependency. doesn't have to be spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply trying to get Maven working? Then perhaps try a mainstream/common dependency e.g. Log4j or Junit?  I tried to follow the URL that is shown in the stack trace (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and traverse the projects to look at the POM etc - below is what I see (no mention of your artifact!).

```
<project ....
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
....
```